# Man goes into murderous rage whenever he hears name of his lover's killer; friend clones the dead girl

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

What short story (and which author) used this plot: a man disturbed by his lover's murder. He develops an amazing power to make big decisions for businesses, governments, etc, but the same condition also triggers murderous rage when hearing the name of his lover's killer.

Charismatic actor/sports hero is hired to help, and creates a clone of the lost love.  (More happens, but that's enough of a spoiler to get the question answered.)

Loved this story every time I read it, but it's been 20 years or more, and I cannot recall the title or the author.

Comment: I'd recommend putting the spoilers in a separate paragraph, prefixed by `>!` to hide them in a spoiler box. In order for that to be useful, however, the title would need to be similarly edited.

Answer (score 19):

["Time Is the Traitor"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40863), a novelette by [Alfred Bester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Bester), first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, September 1953](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61415), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v005n03_1953-09/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v005n03_1953-09#page/n103/mode/2up). Reprinted many times; does any of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?40863) look familiar?

ISFDB synopsis:

> A man who is the only one on Earth who can make good decisions given the vast quantities of data and interconnections, is found to have a deep psychological scar which his friend attempts to heal.

**He develops an amazing power to make big decisions for businesses, governments, etc,**

> There was a man named John Strapp; the most valuable, the most powerful, the most legendary man in a world containing seven hundred planets and 1700 billion people. He was prized for one quality alone. He could make Decisions. Note the capital D. He was one of the few men who could make Major Decisions in a world of incredible complexity, and his Decisions were 87 per cent correct. He sold his Decisions for high prices.

**but the same condition also triggers murderous rage when hearing the name of his lover's killer.**

The killer's name was Kruger:

> "You!" the clerk cried suddenly. His voice screeched horribly. "You son of a bitch! You goddamned lousy murdering bastard! I've been waiting for this. I've waited ten years!" He pulled a flat gun from his inside pocket and shot the man through the forehead.
>
> Time stood still. It took hours for the brains and blood to burst out of the back of the head and for the body to crumple. Then the Strapp staff leaped into action. The hurled the clerk into the ship. The secretaries followed, then the decoy. The two burly men leaped after them and slammed the door. The ship took off and disappeared with a fading whine. The ten men in plain clothes quietly drifted off and vanished. Only Fisher, the Strapp liaison man, was left alongside the body in the center of the horrified crowd.
>
> "Check his identification," Fisher snapped.
>
> Someone pulled the dead man's wallet and opened it.
>
> "William F. Kruger, biomechanic."
>
> "The damned fool!" Fisher said savagely. "We warned him. We warned all the Krugers. All right. Call the police."
>
> That was John Strapp's sixth murder. It cost exactly Cr. 500,000 to fix. The other five had cost the same, and half the amount usually went to a man desperate enough to substitute for the killer and plead temporary insanity. The other half went to the heirs of the deceased. There were six of these substitutes languishing in various penitentiaries, serving from twenty to fifty years, their families Cr. 250,000 richer.

**Charismatic actor/sports hero is hired to help,**

> "Damn it, it doesn't make sense." Fisher thought a moment. "All right. We'll have to hire him a friend, and we'll have to ease off the schedule to give the friend a chance to make Strapp talk. From now on we cut the program to one Decision a week."
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "You mean Fatal Frank Alceste? The heavyweight champ?" the burly man asked in awe. "I saw him fight Lonzo Jordan. Oh, man!"
>
> "He's an actor now," the decoy explained. "I worked with him once. He sings. He dances. He—"
>
> "And he's twice as fatal," Fisher interrupted. "We'll hire him. Make out a contract. He'll be Strapp's friend. As soon as Strapp meets him, he'll—"
>
> "Meets who?" Strapp appeared in the doorway of his bedroom, yawning, blinking at the light. "Who am I going to meet?" He looked around, thin, graceful, but harassed and indubitably possessed.
>
> "A man named Frank Alceste," Fisher said. "He badgered us for an introduction and we can't hold him off any longer."
>
> "Frank Alceste?" Strapp murmured. "Never heard of him."

**and creates a clone of the lost love.**

> But Frankie Alceste kept his own counsel, and visited the Deneb laboratories of Bruxton Biotics. There he consulted with one E. T. A. Goland, the research genius who had discovered that novel technique for molding life which first brought Strapp to Bruxton, and was indirectly responsible for his friendship with Alceste. Ernst Theodor Amadeus Goland was short, fat, asthmatic, and enthusiastic.
>
> "But yes, yes," he sputtered when the layman had finally made himself clear to the scientist. "Yes indeed! A most ingenious notion. Why it never occurred to me, I cannot think. It could be accomplished without any difficulty whatsoever." He considered. "Except money," he added.
>
> "You could duplicate the girl that died ten years ago?" Alceste asked.
>
> "Without any difficulty, except money." Goland nodded emphatically.